# How to access the nid of selected node using nodereference textfield?

Tags: 7, ajax, nodes

I'm using drupal 7.28 and node reference 7.x-2.1

I need to know the nid of a selected node using cck node reference field, not de #default_value of the field but a new one

I've added ajax to the field to perform further tasks with the selected node nid

after I've selected a node with the nodereference cck field, if I use dpm($form_state['input']) the field nid is null

where I should seek (at $form_state) to find out the nid of the selected node ?

Comment: i would suggest dpm ($form_state) and more than likely the nodereference is located in $form_state['values']['field_name']

Comment: thanks but $form['input']['field_name'] just contains the text I input to make the filter over the nodes, and $form_state['values']['field_name']['und'][0]['nid'] contains null